# Prove that a given function is not integrable over any interval $[a,b]$.

Tags: integration, functions

Consider the following function:

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & x\text{ is a rational number}, \\
      1 & x\text{ is an irrational number}. 
   \end{cases}
\
$$

Show that the function $f(x)$ is not integrable over any interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: try to prove the function is not continuos

Comment: @y_andoni There exist integrable non continuous functions

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1079172/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1550808/

Comment: Prove that inf sum is zero and sup sum is $b-a$ so they don't converge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function

Comment: @Raffaele well its not riemann integrable but its integrable as a Lebesgue integral . Since the OP asked to show the function is not integrable i assumed he meant Riemann-integrable. And the function is also non-monotonous so you are only left to check if it is continous or not.

Comment: @y_andoni A function only needs to be continuous almost everywhere to be Riemann integrable.

Comment: @y_andoni, Yes, the question assumes Riemann integration.

Comment: Hint: use the definition of "Riemann-integrable".

Comment: @y_andoni The given function is not continuous on the set of rationals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function does not have left-hand and right-hand limits at each point, hence it is not regulated, hence it is not Riemann-integrable.