# If function $f$ and $g$ aren't Riemann integrable, can the function $f+g$ be?

Tags: riemann-integration

As the question states, if function $f$ and $g$ aren't Riemann integrable, can the sum of the functions be Riemann integrable?

Most importantly, in what way should this be proven?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is *yes*, take $h$ a *non* Riemann integrable function over some $[a,b]$, we have that $-h$ is also *non* Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$ but
$$
-h+h=0
$$which is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious example has already been given: consider any non-Riemann integrable function and its oppossite. Here's a concrete example based on the same idea, consider the indicator functions of the rationals and the irrationals (e.g. on $[0,1]$):
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  & x\in\Bbb Q \\[2ex]
0 & x\notin\Bbb Q
\end{cases} \quad\quad \mbox{and} \quad\quad g(x) =
\begin{cases}
0  & x\in\Bbb Q \\[2ex]
1 & x\notin\Bbb Q
\end{cases}$$
Then $f(x)+g(x) = 1$, clearly Riemann integrable.

See also: [Is the indicator function of the rationals Riemann integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1079172/159845)

Comment: Though that's just the negation idea but with an added constant, you have g = -f + 1

Comment: @ilkkachu You're right of course, but I thought a concrete example could still be useful. I rewrote it a bit to reflect your (good) point.